# Is there a way in python 3 to retrieve data from file which has been read to end and then written some data?

Tags: python

I have a python script which lets me read file to end and after the reading if I enter 'q' then the script tries to read next data. But the script does not retrieve data after I enter 'q'.

## What I did

I have a file **text.txt**. I open this file in a text editor and enter "**qwe**" string and save it.
I run the python script:

```
with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
    print(f.read())
    if input() == "q":
        print(f.read())
```

And it prints "**qwe**".

Then I enter "**123**" string at the new line in file editor and save it.
Then I enter "**q**" at the script and see nothing is printed. But I expected to see "**qwe**" in one line and "**123**" in second line.

Comment: Could you be using Linux (or another Unix-like system)?

Comment: Yes, I use Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File editors are rather clever tools. In order not to lose data in bad conditions, many rename the original file and then save the new file on a plain different file. If anything goes wrong the original file has just to be renamed back, and at least it is still there, and if everything is good the original file is simply removed (or kept as a backup).

But for your use case, the file that your program has an handle on is never modified...

If you want to be able to change a file while a program is using it, you'd better write at the end with `>>`:

```
echo "123" >> text.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `seek` function to rewind the file pointer to the start, i.e. `f.seek(0)`

Comment: I tried it. Unfortunately, it does not help.

Comment: f.seek(0) after you have entered the new data & before the second print statement should work fine.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to achieve. If you want to print conditionally (on user input 'q') you could use `f.seek(0)` before the second `f.read()`. Or you could simply capture the file content on the first `f.read()`: `body = f.read()` and later `print(body)`

Comment: @FreekWiekmeijer, I want to print actual data from file without repeating printed data. If I use `f.seek(0)`, the script prints entire data of file. My script works well. I have noticed that the text editor job is cause of my problem. Because when I use 'echo' command to write to file, my script prints new data.

Comment: Your echo statement is probably adding to the existing wile (using the `>>` redirect). The script is designed to read and print the entire file.  Either you need to overwrite the file (using `>` instead of `>>`) or you need to remember the read offset somewhere.